# Changing service account password

Tags: 2007, administration

I have just started at an organisation and when I review the Event Viewer it is filled with Event 6641 errors. Basically the error is:

---

Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Office SharePoint Server
Event Category: Office Server Shared Services 
Event ID:   6641
Date:       6/04/2011
Time:       12:05:27 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   SHAREPOINT
Description:
The SSP Timer Job Distribution List Import Job was not run.

Reason: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Technical Support Details:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.WindowsSecurity.GetUserTokenFromCredentials(String userDomainName, String password, LogonType logonType)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.WindowsSecurity.GetUserTokenFromCredentials(String userDomainName, String password)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.JobHandler.Execute(Object state, Boolean timedOut)

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

---

After reading some articles, it says that it would appear someone modified the password of the said account but SharePoint hasn't updated it everywhere, so to run the following command:

stsadm –o updatefarmcredentials –userlogin  -password

... and then do a IIS reset/noforce

As I'm not aware of the account password, if I change the password of the account in IIS and then run the above command, is this all that's required? Also, will their be any downtime on the SharePoint WFE / Farm?

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 1):

It is a little more work required. Please see the MS-Support article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934838.